# Ransomware detection software on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, security, ransomware

I'm looking for a software that runs in the background and finds out if in specific directories an abnormal amount of files have been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rkhunter, [chkrootkit](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Chkrootkit) - for rootkits

lmd and [lynis](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Lynis) - also check for rootkits, are not packaged

p.s. [clamav](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/ClamAV) - an anti-virus, can run in real time - plus also [this guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/index.en.html)